# When there is an electric malfunction in an electrical equipment or device

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine two electrical wires have layd over on each other and both of them have some naked parts. Or there is such a situation in a pug or in a socket.
It has caused some problems for the connected devices and those electrical equipment. How one can describe such a situation:

> - There is an electrical malfunction with this (plug / socket / wire).
> - This (plug / socket / wire) has an electrical malfunction.

Which one of the above sentences sound natural to a native speaker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, and either could be used to describe the situation you've laid out. However, it's quite a cumbersome turn of phrase, and a more natural way of expressing this might be to use the expression [**short circuit**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short%20circuit) - an electrical connection made between points in an electric circuit between which current does not normally flow, for example, if the insulation had become worn away in two wires, as you describe. To give an example of usage:

> - There is a **short circuit** in this plug/socket/wire.
> - This plug/socket/wire has a **short circuit**.

More informally one might say:

> - This plug/socket/wire has **shorted out**.

Answer (score 2):

They are both equally acceptable to an English speaker.  The situation you describe is called an "electrical short."  "This plug has a short"  or "This plug has an electrical short" are both acceptable, and sound more natural than the word "malfunction."